# Get the current activity in a static method in a non-View class

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to access the current activity from a static method on a non-View class, I want to know if this apporach is a good one or not:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyActivity mCurrentActivity;
    private static void setCurrentActivity(MyActivity currentActivity) {
        mCurrentActivity = currentActivity;
    }
    private static MyActivity getCurrentActivity() {
        return mCurrentActivity;
    }
}
```

And then I'm gonna create a custom activity named `MyActiviy` and use it for all my application's activities, This is how `MyActivity` is gonna be:

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication.setCurrentActivity(this);
    }
}
```

Then, whenever I want to get an instance of the current activity, I just call the `MyApplication.getCurrentActivity()` method. I know this code is gonna work but I just wanna know if this is a good thing to use this approach?

I know I can just pass the activity as a parameter to the static method but I want a global way of accessing the current activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this code is gonna work but I just wanna know if this is a good thing to use this approach?

You are leaking memory. That instance of that activity, and everything that it holds onto, cannot be garbage collected, so long as you have a reference to it from the `Application`.

Beyond this, the `Application` is not really helping you here. If you are going leak memory, at least be more efficient in terms of the implementation, and use a simple `static` field.

Comment: I don't understand how this is leaking memory? When I'm at the same activity the field stays the same. whenever I move to another activity, that field is gonna be set to the new activity. The previous activity is still in the memory since when I go back it is still there. Is this correct?

Comment: @m2008m1033m: "When I'm at the same activity the field stays the same. whenever I move to another activity, that field is gonna be set to the new activity" -- there are more navigation paths than just moving forward. At minimum, you would need to ensure that in all those paths that your global reference is pointing to the correct activity. This includes things like dealing with unhandled exceptions, configuration changes, and the like.

Comment: So is there another way to achieve this or must I pass the activity to whatever method needs it?

Comment: @m2008m1033m: Pass the activity to whatever method needs it. The only type of `Context` that is safe to hold globally is the `Application` instance itself, as that is a singleton created as part of starting up your process, so it is "pre-leaked", if you will. Even then, I won't put the `Application` itself in a `static` field, though I will put other things that might hold onto an `Application` in a `static` field (e.g., a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`).